# How to disable <InputText> AspNetCore Component

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

It seems `<InputText>` does not have a `disabled` property. Am I using it wrong or is there an abnormal way to disable the field?

```
<div class="input-group form-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="oi oi-key"></i></span>
    </div>
    <InputText @bind-Value="@Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" type="password"></InputText>
</div>
<div class="input-group form-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="oi oi-key"></i></span>
    </div>
    <input type"text" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
```

[image]

As you can see a normal `<input>` field can be disabled just fine. I would like all the functionality of `<InputText>` so prefer not to switch components for my password field.

Comment: `<InputText>`  is a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Component in case that was not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All components you can use in an `EditForm` support any html attibute.
You can disabled the `InputText`with:

```cs
<InputText @bind-Value="@Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
type="password" disabled ></InputText>
<InputText @bind-Value="@Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
type="password" disabled="disabled" ></InputText>
```

Note: `placeholder`, `type` and `class` aren't `InputText` properties neither.

Comment: Thank you. I was thrown off by the slow syntax highlighting.